# Who are the MCU directors, producers, and actors in this photo?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, actor-identification

To celebrate the tenth anniversary of Marvel Studios, Marvel released this picture featuring actors, directors, writers, and producers from all the MCU movies.

Click the image to view the full size.

### Who are the MCU actors, directors, writers, and producers in this photo?

[image: Marvel Studios 10th anniversary photo]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to ScreenRant's [article on the matter](https://screenrant.com/mcu-10-year-cast-photo-every-actor/), a complete list of the actors was available. Combining this with [this reddit thread on the matter](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelstudios/comments/7w69wn/10_years_in_the_making/dtxtyhb/) provides us with the full list below, with directors and writers and their respective roles, and actors and their main/first role (in comment below the one linked). A visual is of the below list is provided at the bottom.

> ## All names are Left to Right
>
> ### Top Row
>
> Christopher Marcus & Stephen McFeely (Writers, Captain America Triolgy, Avengers 3-4, Thor: The Dark World, Agent Carter)
>   Michael Rooker (Yondu, Guardians of the Galaxy)
>   Vin Diesel (Groot, Guardians of the Galaxy)
>   Cobie Smulders (Maria Hill, Avengers)
>   Samuel L. Jackson (Nick Fury, Avengers)
>   Taika Waititi (Korg/Director, Thor: Ragnarok)
>   Jeff Goldblum (Grandmaster, Thor: Ragnarok)
>   Eric Hausserman Carroll (Co-Producer)
>   Ryan Meinerding (Head of Visual Development)
>   Craig Kyle (Writer, Thor: Ragnarok)
>
> ### Third Level, Standing/Seated Left
>
> Peyton Reed (Director, Ant-Man, Ant-Man & the Wasp)
>   Laurence Fishburne (Bill Foster, Ant-Man)
>   Linda Cardellini (Laura Barton, Avengers)
>   Johnathan Schwartz (Executive Producer)
>   Sebastian Stan (Winter Soldier/Bucky Barnes, Captain America)
>   Ty Simpkins (Harley Keener, Iron Man 3)
>
> ### Level 3.5
>
> Mark Ruffalo (Hulk, Avengers)
>   Brie Larson (Captain Marvel, Captain Marvel)
>   Michael Douglas (Hank Pym, Ant-Man)
>   Stephen Broussard (Co-producer)
>
> ### Third Level, Standing/Seated Right
>
> Ryan Coogler (Director, Black Panther)
>   Michelle Pfieffer (Janet Van Dyne, Ant-Man)
>   Jeremy Latcham (Former Senior Vice-President, Marvel Studios)
>   Hayley Atwell (Peggy Carter, Captain America/Agent Carter)
>   Pom Klementieff (Mantis, Guardians of the Galaxy)
>   Nate Moore (Co-producer)
>   Benedict Wong (Wong, Doctor Strange)
>
> ### Second level, Seated/Standing Left
>
> Jon Watts (Director, Spider-Man Homecoming, Spider-Man Homecoming 2)
>   Sarah Finn (Casting Director)
>   Tessa Thompson (Valkryie, Thor: Ragnarok)
>   David Grant (Co-Producer)
>   Don Cheadle (War Machine, Iron Man)
>   Tom Holland (Spider-Man, Spider-Man Homecoming)
>   James Gunn (Director, Guardians of the Galaxy trilogy)
>
> ### Level 2.5
>
> Dave Bautista (Drax, Guardians of the Galaxy)
>   Michael Pena (Luis, Ant-Man)
>   Anthony Mackie (Falcon, Captain America)
>   Evangeline Lilly (Wasp, Ant-Man)
>   Joe & Anthony Russo (Directors, Captain America 2-3, Avengers 3-4)
>   Chris Pratt (Star-Lord, Guardians of the Galaxy)
>   Chadwick Boseman (Black Panther, Black Panther)
>   Benedict Cumberbatch (Doctor Strange, Doctor Strange)
>   Elizabeth Olsen (Scarlet Witch, Avengers)
>   Joss Whedon (Director, Avengers, Avengers: Age of Ultron)
>
> ### Second level, Seated/Standing Right
>
> Paul Bettany (Jarvis/Vision, Avengers)
>   Mitchell Bell (Co-producer)
>   Frank Grillo (Crossbones, Captain America)
>   Anna Boden (Director, Captain Marvel)
>   Ryan Fleck (Director, Captain Marvel)
>   Letitia Wright (Shuri, Black Panther)
>   Adam McKay  (Writer, Ant-Man)
>
> ### Bottom Level
>
> Sean Gunn (Kraglin/Rocket on-set preformer, Guardians of the Galaxy)
>   Hannah John-Kamen (Ghost, Ant-Man)
>   Scott Derrickson (Director, Doctor Strange)
>   Trinh Tran (Creative Executive)
>   Jeremy Renner (Hawkeye, Avengers)
>   Paul Rudd (Ant-Man/Writer, Ant-Man)
>   Victoria Alonso (Marvel Studios Executive Vice-President Physical Production)
>   Zoe Saldana (Gamora, Guardians of the Galaxy)
>   Angela Bassett (Ramonda, Black Panther)
>   Jon Favreau (Happy Hogan, Iron Man/Avengers; Writer, Iron Man 1-2)
>   Chris Hemsworth (Thor, Thor)
>   Gwneth Paltrow (Pepper Potts, Iron Man)
>   Chris Evans (Captain America, Captain America)
>   Stan Lee (Tons of Cameos, all; Executive Producer, all)
>   Scarlett Johansson (Black Widow, Avengers)
>   Luis D'Esposito (Marvel Studios, Co-President)
>   Kurt Russell (Ego, Guardians of the Galaxy)
>   Danai Gurira (Okoye, Black Panther)
>   William Hurt (Thaddeus Ross, Incredible Hulk)
>   Alan Taylor (Director, Thor: The Dark World)
>   Karen Gillan (Nebula, Guardians of the Galaxy)
>   Brad Winderbaum (Marvel Studios Vice-President: Production & Development)
>   Emily VanCamp (Sharon Carter, Captain America)
>   Louis Leterrier (Director, The Incredible Hulk)
>
> ### Very bottom row
>
> Robert Downey Jr. (Iron Man, Iron Man)
>   Kevin Feige (Marvel Studios President)

In total there are:
48 Actors,
13 Directors,
6 Writers,
15 Executives/Producers,
1 Stan Lee

[image: 10th anniversary marvel studios photo]

Comment: Yep, it's irrefutable that Stan Lee is indeed a category of his own :)